# Are conditionals in ModRewrite possible?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a simple piece of ModRewrite that channels everything to index.php if it's not an existing file or directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now I want to add a exception when the domain contains certain strings, but I don't know how to to add this. I was thinking of adding the following.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(aanmelding|keyclamps|probouw)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project.php/$1 [L]
```

**UPDATE, I found a partial solution**
If I put it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# If not an old project
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(aanmelding|keyclamps|probouw)

# forward it to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Else
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# forward it to project.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project.php/$1 [L]
```

It works, but with a bug. Because index.php exists, the second part of the conditional still goes to index.php instead of project.php when a plain domain is called like http://probouw.localhost/

Any ideas?

Comment: Does "does not work" mean that you are always redirected to `index.php`?

Comment: Oh no, I get a server error, so it's incorrect to start with. Separately they don't produce the error.

Comment: Apache errors normally get logged. Do you have access to logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone that might need this, the solution was:

```
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# If not an old project
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(aanmelding|keyclamps|probouw)

# forward it to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Else 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/

# forward it to project.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using OR would help (NC=NotCase sensitive by the way)?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*aanmelding.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*keyclamps.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*probouw.*$ [NC]
```

Comment: this solution also works (sorry for my description, 'contains' should have been 'starts with' but I get your code). Still got a bug in there though (see my update). How do I get it to go to project.php when index.php also exists?

Comment: Ok, sorry, too little time right now. Perhaps you can avoid it by renaming index.php to something like default.php?

Comment: No, problem. Thanks! I can't rename index.php So I used your code to try this 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/$

But that wasn't it either

Answer (score 0):

In reference to your partial solution, if you change the last part does this work?

```
# forward it to project.php
RewriteRule ^/?$ /project.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ /project.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thx! But it didn't work. Seems to me that the problem is that "/" is a not a valid condition because root exists and the RewriteRules are not even excecuted.

Comment: Do you know how to make the RewriteRule also excecute when REQUEST_FILENAME is "/". I tried %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/$ But that didn't work.